# Synaptics-Touchpad (xorg-xserver) tap sensitivity too high

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, synaptic

I have a Lenovo x1 carbon 7th gen. I just recently installed the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` to fix the disabled click buttons after suspension.

Since I have installed the synaptics driver, the tap functionality of the touchpad itself is extremely high. Everytime I type on the keyboard, I activate a click on the touchpad, and when I click on the "activity" Icon in gnome it often registers two clicks.

From what I found out so far, I should change the options in `synclient` to alter this behaviour. But I cannot figure out which options need to be altered to fix this behaviour.

I am using the latest Pop OS version, which basically is Ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=765447#p765447) answers your question.

> 1. Run `xinput`.
> 2. Get the id number of the touchpad.
> 3. Then run this command: `xinput list-props X` (where X is the id number you just obtained).
> 4. Then you can change your synaptic finger values by following [this guide](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=765618#p765618).